# R Shiny - Generating report

Tags: r, shiny

I want to export the html/pdf file from shiny app and I found this
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html.

Then I tried to use the code from this website which is shown blow:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
      output$report <- downloadHandler(
  # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.html",
      content = function(file) {
    # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
    # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
    # can happen when deployed).
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)

    # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
    # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
    # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
          params = params,
          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )})}

ui <- fluidPage(
     sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
     downloadButton("report", "Generate report"))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, I cannot download the report (Failed-Server problem) and got error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3638
Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
  path[1]="/tmp/Rtmp1BbjoR/test.Rmd": No such file or directory
Warning: Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute: file '/tmp/Rtmp1BbjoR/test.Rmd' does not exist
Stack trace (innermost first):
    58: tools::file_path_as_absolute
    57: dirname
    56: setwd
    55: rmarkdown::render
    54: download$func [example_code/report.R#23]
     5: <Anonymous>
     4: do.call
     3: print.shiny.appobj
     2: print
     1: print
Error : file '/tmp/Rtmp1BbjoR/test.Rmd' does not exist
```

I am working on R server. Is there any suggestion in terms of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `file.copy` doesn't copy your report to temp folder. Make sure the report is in current directory `print(getwd())`

Comment: Thanks @HubertL, I created a blank report file in current directory and it works. However, the report I download is still a blank report. It seems the overwrite argument doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue : rendering a blank report producing a blank report sounds to me like an expected behavior

Comment: @HubertL Actually I don't think I rendered a blank report. As the tutorial said this app takes one input value, and passes it as a parameter to an .Rmd document, which is rendered (or knitted) into an HTML output file. Also I tried this http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/generating-reports.html (same code as I post) and the downloaded report was not a blank report. In stead it returns parameters and plot which is my goal.

Comment: so why did you state in your prvious comment : I created a blank report file in current directory?

Comment: @HubertL Since I did create a blank Rmd file in current directory and now I know I shouldn't create blank Rmd file tho. Problem solved and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the example on the website, a skeletal `.Rmd` (named `report.Rmd`, preferably created as an `R` script, to avoid invisible `.txt` ext.) file needs to be present in your working directory. The content of this shell file is given on the webpage referred to in the question. So the steps are:

1. Create a file, `report.Rmd`, with contents from the stated webpage. Be sure that it doesn't have a `.txt` extension.
2. Place it in the working directory of the R session.
3. Run the code as is.